# What statistical method will I use if I want to compare 10 caloric values of rice samples to a suggested amount?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

We've conducted a comparative study on the caloric values of rice sample from different food stalls found within our  university and we want to compare it to a suggested caloric value of per-meal rice intake.

Say, we have these theoretical values (in Calories) for our rice samples:

2,2,4,3,5,2,3,3,4,3

and we want to compare it to '3'. What statistical method is fit for such circumstance and how could we possible interpret the result of the statistical treatment.

Comment: What do you mean by "we have these *theoretical* values"?

Comment: What comparison do you wish to make? What is the point of the comparison?

Answer (score 1):

A regular one-sample t-test. By default a t-test tests whether the sample mean is different from 0, however you can change this into any arbitrary number, such as 3. From a t-test you would get your sample mean, it's confidence interval and associated p-value.

**Edit:** To clarify, a t-test requires your sample to be roughly normally distributed as this is an assumption of the model. If this is not true than a non-parametric test could be used, although comparing means in this case may not be as easy or sensible.

Comment: But a t- test assumes you are estimating the mean of a normal distributed population. This might be easily violated. For instance, if you measure rice from the *same stall* then you expect errors to be caused by many small incremental errors which together become an error of measurement that is approximately normal distributed and whose impact can be quantified by using the sample variance. However if you consider *different stalls* than the source of "error" may be fixed effects that are not normal distributed, for instance variations due to different types of cooking and/or types of rice.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings You are right in that a one-sample t-test requires the *sample* data to be normally distributed. This may not be true in this case, I just assumed this would be true.